# Finally block not working in JAVA Stored procedure for Oracle

Tags: java, scope, try-catch-finally

When I compile the below code, it shows error "cannot find symbol variable out"
But if i comment the code in the finally block, I am able to compile successfully.

Please advise.

```
public static int writeFile (String p_file_path, String p_data) throws Exception 
{
  try {
    FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(p_file_path,true);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);
    out.println(p_data);
  } catch (Exception  e) {
  } finally {
    out.close();
  }
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to define "out" outside try-block if you want to reference it in the finally block, something like

```
PrintWriter out = null;
try
{
    FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(p_file_path,true);
    out = new PrintWriter(outFile);
    out.println(p_data);
}
finally
{
    if (out != null)
        out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You declare `out` within the `try` block. This means that is out of scope as soon as you leave the `try` portion of your `try-finally` statement. You can either declare it outside of your `try` statement and do a null check in your `finally` block, or use Java 7's [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

```
PrintWriter out;
try {
    out = ...
} finally {
    if(out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

or

```
try(PrintWriter out = ...) {
}
```

Comment: Hey Jeffrey. Thanks. Declaring outside the try statement worked.

Comment: eis's answer is better because he initialized the variable `out` and saved me a compiler error.